# How to configure in Spartacus a different OCC baseUrl in CSR app vs SSR app

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Normally in Spartacus, both SSR and CSR app use the same OCC `baseUrl` configuration:

```js
   provideConfig(
      backend: {
        occ: {
          baseUrl: 'https://some.baseUrl.com'
        },
      },
    }),
```

But how to configure **a different OCC base url** in CSR app vs SSR app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of providing a static config, you can provide a **config factory**, which takes the `PLATFORM_ID` and checks whether it is a *browser* or not. Then, conditionally, you can return a config chunk with a different OCC base url. See the following example:

```js
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { OccConfig, provideConfigFactory } from '@spartacus/core';

function myOccConfigFactory(): OccConfig {
  const platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  const isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  const baseUrl = isBrowser
    ? 'https://baseUrl.for.browser'
    : 'https://baseUrl.for.ssr';

  return { backend: { occ: { baseUrl } } };
}

/* ... */
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    /* ... */,
    provideConfigFactory(myOccConfigFactory),
  ]
})
```

Note: The technique of using `provideConfigFactory` with injecting `PLATFORM_ID` allows for providing any type of Spartacus confiugration (not only the OCC base url) differently in CSR vs SSR.